# Strong instances under Divs - only capturing initial instance

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've got a small issue with my code. Effectively I am aiming to get the following instances out of some code:

```
<td>
<div>
<div>8 of 15 — <strong>53%</strong></div>
<div><div style="width: 100%"><div style="width: 53%"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

I'm trying to capture the data in div, prior to the strong, as well as the strong percentage. Currently working with the following to get these data but I am only able to either get the a) first instance, or b) null values:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as reqs

other_stat_list = []

page_to_parse = 'https://fbref.com/en/matches/033092ef/Northampton-Town-Lincoln-City-August-4-2018-League-Two'

page = reqs.get(page_to_parse)
status_code = page.status_code
status_code = str(status_code)
parse_page = bsoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


find_other_stats = parse_page.find_all('div', id="team_stats")
for stat in find_other_stats:
    add_other_stats = stat.find_next('strong').get_text()
    other_stat_list.append(add_other_stats)
    print(add_other_stats)
```

I had a similar problem before, where not all div instances were captured. I ran a recursion to capture all the children in the code:

```
find_other_stats = parse_page.find_all('div', id="team_stats")
all_other_stats = find_other_stats[0].find_all('div', recursive=False)
for stat in all_other_stats:
    add_other_stats = find_next('strong').get_text()
     other_stat_list.append(add_team)
```

However a variant of this produces nulls as well, so not sure why the recursion is not working.

Expecting to get '53%' and ideally '8 of 15 -. I can parse the values themselves, but capturing them looks to be tougher than I expected. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code I get all parts as separated elements.

First: there is only one `div` with `id="team_stats"` so I use `find()` instead of `find_all()`

Instead of searchig `div` I search `td` and I use `get_text()` I get full text in cell. This way I don't need recursion for nested `<div>` and I don't get empty string from empty `<div>`.

After getting all text from all cells in table I split it to smaller parts and clean them.

I split it by `—` to get `53%` and `8 of 15` as separated elements. But `—` is not normal `-` so I manually copied/pasted it from HTML to code.

I found that there is also char with code `'\xa0'` (which can be "non-breaking space" or something similar) and  I clean it using `strip('\xa0')` - I could also use `rstrip()`/`lstrip()` or ``` replace()`` or slice it with ```[1:]`and`[:-1]`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests 

url = 'https://fbref.com/en/matches/033092ef/Northampton-Town-Lincoln-City-August-4-2018-League-Two'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')

# --- getting data ---

data = []

stats = soup.find('div', id="team_stats")

for row in stats.find_all('td'):
    text = row.get_text(strip=True)
    data.append(text)

# --- splitting and cleaning data ---

print('Possession:', data[0], '|', data[1])

text1, percent1 = data[2].split('—')
percent2, text2 = data[3].split('—')
text1 = text1.strip('\xa0')
text2 = text2.strip('\xa0')
print('Shots on Target:', text1, '|', percent1, '|', text2, '|', percent2)

text1, percent1 = data[4].split('—')
percent2, text2 = data[5].split('—')
text1 = text1.strip('\xa0')
text2 = text2.strip('\xa0')
print('Saves:', text1, '|', percent1, '|', text2, '|', percent2)
```

Result:

```
Possession: 58% | 42%
Shots on Target: 8 of 15 | 53% | 2 of 4 | 50%
Saves: 1 of 2 | 50% | 8 of 8 | 100%
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, didn't even think find() was a good swap. Thanks furas!